# $\int _{|z|=1} (\frac{e^z}{z+2} - 3 \bar z) dz $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I stumbled on this question. Could you help me?

$\int _{|z|=1} (\frac{e^z}{z+2} - 3 \bar z) dz $

I know that the answer is -$6\pi i $

I was trying to use the Cauchy's integral formula

Answer (score 1):

You stumble a lot.

On $|z|=1$, $\overline z=1/z$ so your integral is
$$\int_{|z|=1}\left(\frac{e^z}{z+2}-\frac3z\right)\,dz.$$
I think $z=0$ is the only pole of the integrand inside the
contour of integration.